# Get stuck in building Spark-1.1.0 with sbt (how to "set current project to spark-parent")

Tags: sbt, apache-spark

I am compiling spark-1.1.0 using sbt (# sbt/sbt -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0) on Ubuntu 1204 64-bit. There have already been several other versions of spark (0.9.1 and 1.0.0) on my computer. At first everything goes normally, but then I got stuck (the build process stopped waiting with a ">") as follows. So how to "Set current project to spark-parent"? Thank you for your help!

```
[warn] Multiple resolvers having different access mechanism configured with same name 'sbt-plugin-releases'. To avoid conflict, Remove duplicate project resolvers (`resolvers`) or rename publishing resolver (`publishTo`).

[info] Loading project definition from /root/spark-1.1.0/project

[info] Set current project to spark-parent (in build file:/root/spark-1.1.0/)

\>
```

John.

Comment: What, exactly, do you type in your shell to "build" spark ? let's start with `cd spark-1.1.0`. What comes next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @huitseeker.

I guess the problem is due to multiple versions of spark on my machine. So I used another machine with Ubuntu #1404# and do a clean-slate compilation. This time I used maven (# mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean package) and everything seems OK.

Note that (i) you may restart the compilation several time due to network problems; and (ii) before the compilation you may need to remove the folder "~/.m2" to prevent interference from previous compilations.

cheers,

John